# Batch processing: strip channel

Tags: audacity, batch-processing

I'm using Audacity to process some short audio clips - about 300 of them (!!!), so I'd really rather not repeat my steps manually for each one.

However, I can't seem to find a way to create a chain which includes the "split stereo track & discard right channel" step. I'm at my wits' end; is there any way to do this? If not, is there another program that would let me do this in an automated fashion?

Answer (score 3):

Use ffmpeg

If you want to mute the first channel and keep the second:

ffmpeg -i INPUT -map_channel -1 -map_channel 0.0.1 OUTPUT